# Nextjs MongoDB template: clientPromise is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am using Next.js's MongoDB example template and it comes with a MongoDB util function:

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local');
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}
export default clientPromise;
```

Here is how I am using it and I am certain that I am using this incorrectly.

```js
import { clientPromise } from '../../lib/mongodb';

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const db = await clientPromise();
    const users = await db.collection('users').find({}).limit(20).toArray();
    res.json(users);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.json({ error: 'Not connected!' });
  }
};
```

The error is "TypeError: (0 , *lib_mongodb__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.clientPromise) is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting `clientPromise`, which is `client.connect()`. At this point you already "triggered" the connection function. now all you have to do is wait on that promise,

So instead of

```
const db = await clientPromise();
```

You should do:

```
const connection = await clientPromise; // this is a client connection not a db
const db = connection.db();
```